# CircleCI - How to build and test in a sub directory?

Tags: python, symfony, continuous-integration, circleci, openedx

I have an online course platform project. The tree looks like this:

```
app
-- edxapp
   -- edx-platform
      -- circle.yml
```

I want to run the circle.yml in the edx-platform directory. I've followed their documentation [here](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#build-dir).

First, I created a new circle.yml in the root directory so that the tree looks like this:

```
circle.yml
app
-- edxapp
   -- edx-platform
      -- circle.yml
```

The new circle.yml contains the following:

```
general:
  build_dir: app/edxapp/edx-platform
```

But, it still didn't work. Then I tried another way. I linked the circle.yml files so that I have one circle.yml in each directory. Each circle.yml just contains the build_dir key with its value pointing to the next sub directory.

Please give me an explanation why this doesn't work. Also, please give me an alternative way to do it.

Note: The project structure has to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`circle.yml` needs to be in the root directory of a repository. That file in any other location will not be processed by CircleCI. Anything that you need to do (any commands, etc), needs to be done from that root file.

`build-dir` changes where the commands from `circle.yml` are run from, not where the file should be. In essence, whichever directory is set as `build-dir`, that becomes the working directory for commands in `circle.yml`. More details in [CircleCI Docs](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#build-dir).

---

In summary, have only 1 `circle.yml` directory, in the root of your repository. If you had a command `ls`, this would print the directory listing for `~/MY-REPO-NAME`. If you set the `build-dir` to:

```
general:
  build_dir: app/edxapp/edx-platform
```

then that same `ls` command will now print the directory listing of `~/MY-REPO-NAME/app/edxapp/edx-platform`.

Regards,
Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: Is it still the case that you cannot have `.circleci/config.yml` files in multiple subdirectories? Perhaps a root one that includes/imports them all?

Comment: Yes this is still the case.

Comment: you can have them in multiple subdirectories now, but telling circleci how to use them correctly is not trivial.